# Google translate in-app, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, iphone, rest, google-translate

Is it possible to translate a webpage within a webuiview using google translate?

I am aware that you can use their rest services to translate some text, but I have not found any way to translate a web page.

You can do some trick with the url but that adds along with the translate page a banner at the top that I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST service preserves the HTML however it doesn't take as a parameter a page only content and the content is limited to 5k.

The solution that I have found although not completely out of the box is the following:
http://positionabsolute.net/blog/2009/01/google-translate-made-easy.php

Google documentation helps too
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#TransliterationHTMLContentType